# React + Laravel, should I do it in 1 or 2 seperate repositories?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native

After learning Laravel basics and React.js basics I want to build an app that use Laravel for backend and React.js for frontend. Would it be better to include the React.js in Laravel app with artisan ui react or do it in 2 seperate repositories, 1 for Laravel to build APIs and include it in an addon domain e.g [www.api.mywebsite.com](http://www.api.mywebsite.com) which would act as a backend website and redirect to the React.js app if accessed by public and 1 for React.js app that would be used for public, on the main domain e.g [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) which would just fetch data over [www.api.mywebsite.com](http://www.api.mywebsite.com). So which way is better as I'm developing both frontend and backend, and I also plan on learning and developing React Native mobile apps that would use the same Laravel backend?

Answer (score 0):

Both alternatives work just fine, but it's easier to set up an **api.mywebsite.com** subdomain. Since you are going to also develop mobile apps that will connect to the API, that strengthens the argument of separating the API from the front-end app.